# insert attachment getcontentaspdf not loading data dynamically

Tags: apex, attachment, dynamic, getcontentaspdf

I have a method that call a vf page and render as pdf the following

```
Pagereference test = new Pagereference ('/apex/claire');
return test;
```

that gives me the page I am expecting

[image]

after that the method is supposed to save the attachment to my custom object :

```
boite1 = listakta[i].Type_of_alert__c;
boite2  = listakta[i].text1__c;    
boite3 = listakta[i].comment__c;
boite4 = listakta[i].date__c;
PageReference pdf = new PageReference('apex/claire');              
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
pdf.getParameters().put('boite1', boite1);
ID accID = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
parent= listakta[i].id;
body = pdf.getContentaspdf();
attach.Body = body;
attach.Name = 'test1.pdf';
attach.IsPrivate = false;
attach.ParentId = parent;
insert attach;
```

Unfortunately when it saves the data, it does only save the vf page (claire) without the dynamic content

[image]

Where the dynamic content is boite1, boite2, boite3 and boite4

So the problem is that the page is generated nicely and work, but the attachment is not loading the data that created before. (not synchronous)

Please help me as I tried so many things and it's not working

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `new PageReference('apex/claire')` instead of just `Page.claire`?  I don't see why you need to use a partial URL since you are not redirecting to this page.

Comment: That doesn't change the problem of the dynamic data not loading @DavidCheng